# Show that for any $Z\subseteq Y$, $Z$ is closed in $X$

Tags: general-topology

Be $X$ a topological space and $Y \subseteq X$ closed in $X$. Suppose $Y$, with the subspace-induced topology, is a discrete space. Show that for any $Z\subseteq Y$, $Z$ is closed in $X$.

I wonder if my solution is correct.

If $Y$ is a discrete space so any subset of $Y$ belongs to the $Y$ topology.

(i) Can I say that if $Y$, with the subspace-induced topology, is a discrete space then $X$ is a discrete topological space due to this?

If yes, I can say that if $Y$ is closed then $Y$ is not in the $X$ topology, as $Z$ is a subset of $Y$, it means that $Z$ is not an element of the $X$ topology, so it is closed.

Comment: (i) Consider $Y=\mathbb N$ and $X=\mathbb R$

Answer (score 1):

Answer to $(i)$: No, in general you cannot say this. Pick $X=[0,2]$ and $Y=\{1\}$. You easily see that $X$ is not a discrete space.

Comment: Could you give me a hint? I know that if $Y$ has the discreet topology then all open is closed, said I know that $Z$ is closed in $Y$, but how to prove that it is closed in $X$?

Comment: How can you prove that fact?

Comment: If $Y$ is closed in $X$, then every closed set in $Y$ in the subspace topology is closed in $X$ in the original topology. This holds in general for every subspace topology, even if $Y$ is not discrete. Indeed, by definition of subspace topology, a closed set in $Y$ can be written as the intersection of a closed set of $X$ with $Y$. Since $Y$ is closed, the result follows since the intersection of two closed sets is closed (in $X$).

Comment: @milou, I just noticed that in your questions you often receive good answers from people that help you. In the case you are satisfied (not by mine only, also from ones of others that may likely be even better than mine), you should accept the answer that most have helped you clicking the bottom near the answer to have the green tick. We are happy to help you :)

Comment: hi @milou; I'd like to second Ero's comment above. it looks like you've received a lot of good answers on this website but never accepted any of them. perhaps none of the answers you've received have been helpful to you, in which case that's fine, but if someone posts an answer that you *do* find helpful then it's good etiquette to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and upvote it. this is not only a polite way of thanking the answerer for the work that they put in, but also marks the question as answered to help avoid clutter on the site

Comment: @milou, can you please accept the answers that have been useful to you? We see that you asked 17 questions without accepting any answer. This is definitely not polite and you should at least try to follow the rules of this site.

Answer (score 0):

If $T_X$ is the topology on $X$ then the subspace topology on any $Y\subset X$ is $T_Y=\{t\cap Y: t\in T_X\}.$ It follows  that if $Z\subset Y\subset X$ then $Cl_Y(Z)=Y\cap Cl_X (Z).$

If $Z\subset Y$ then $Cl_X(Z)\subset Cl_X(Y)$  so $Cl_X(Z)\cap Cl_X(Y)=Cl_X(Z).$

So if $Z=Cl_Y(Z)$ and $Y=Cl_X(Y)$ then $$Z=Cl_Y(Z)=Y\cap Cl_X(Z)=Cl_X(Y)\cap Cl_X(Z)=Cl_X(Z).$$ In other words, if $Z$ is closed in $Y$ and $Y$ is closed in $X$ then $Z$ is closed in $X.$

Now if $Y$ is discrete then any $Z\subset Y$ is closed in $Y.$

$Y$ could be the empty space, which is a closed discrete subspace of every space $X$ so you cannot say that $X$ must be discrete. If you meant to ask whether $Z$ is discrete, then yes, every subspace of a discrete space is discrete.

Comment: okay, thank you!!!